# WCF open-source project to learn from

Tags: wcf, open-source

Aiming to be a WCF professional, I am looking for a WCF open source project, from which I can learn and hopefully become a contributor. Can you recommend of such a project?

Comment: WCF alone typically isn't the focus of a project - it's a component inside many projects, but I don't know of any specific "WCF" projects in the open source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good one (albeit not easiest) is [StockTrader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/bb499684) which features enterprise-level WCF services and configurations, in Service-Oriented architecture.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) project has an ongoing effort for WCF hosted in [Github](https://github.com/mono/mono). As you know, [System.ServiceModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145010.aspx) is the main engine for WCF. You can find Mono implementations of these namespaces under `/mono/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel.*` . You can find project related updates and relevant contribution information [here](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development)

Comment: -1: he's looking for samples, not the source

Comment: @JohnSaunders Please read "I am looking for a WCF open source project" & "..learn and hopefully become a contributor.." before down voting. You don't become a contributor to a sample.

Comment: I read that, and I believe he's talking about some open source project that uses WCF, not the open source project that develops WCF.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If you believe that way, I would recommend to edit the question and not down vote an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, even though I will no be accepting it.